# How do I get videos to show up in Google Videos?

Tags: php, html, video, html5-video

I have a website with embedded videos and they are indexed in Google, but not in the videos tab. Is there a special format to get Google to recognize these as videos? Should they be enclosed in the `<video></video>` tags and uploaded directly? Is there any way to use embedded iframes in order to be indexed in Google Videos?

Note: I am asking for CODING (not SEO) assistance, if you can please advise. I would appreciate it, thank you. I would like to know the proper coding format for a video to be recognized by Google Videos. When I searched Google, I found a bunch of irrelevant results.

Answer (score 0):

Those videos are all videos hosted on youtube. So there is no real specific code that will help your videos appear in that tab short of following best practices for youtube video SEO. I would suggest hosting your videos there with accurate titles, tags, good thumbnails etc and then embedding it here and there.

I know you asked for coding suggestions but there aren't any. Those videos are either matched from youtube or well written pages that have a youtube video embedded that fits the subject matter.

Comment: I followed one of the non-YouTube links and it didn't seem to be a YouTube embedded video. Right clicking the video (I clicked on) said, "about BrightCove". I don't think all indexed videos originated from YouTube. But, I'll take the suggestion and just try to use best practices and see if I can get my videos indexed. I appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: I did something similar. For example I searched "css grid" the video in the first result by CSS-TRICKS if you view page source and find it links to youtube. Regardless seeing as google owns youtube and directly benefits from directing users there. I can assure you more than likely all the top pages will be links directly to youtube. Or a youtube video in an article.